# MYSQL Search Question

Tags: mysql, search

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=uft8_general_ci" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<script src="javascript/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Myhalal Check</title>
<meta content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3" name="keywords" />
<meta content="Description of your page" name="description" />







</head>

<body class="list">

<div id="topbar"class="black">
<div id="title">
        <span style="color: #ff006f; ">my</span>hala<span style="color: #fff70a; ">check</span></div>
<div id="rightnav">
        <a href="About.html">About</a>

</div>
<div id ="leftnav">
<a href="Submit.html">Submit</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="searchbox">
    <form action="Search.php" method="get">
        <fieldset><input name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />
        <input id="submit" type="hidden" name="search" /></fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
<div id="content">
<ul>        
<?php
$search = $_GET['search'];

$host = "x"; 
$user = "x"; 
$pass = "x"; 
$db = "x";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); 
mysql_select_db($db); 
unset($host,$user,$pass,$db); 



//$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '1'";
$query = "SELECT produkt FROM checklist WHERE id LIKE '%$search%'";  
$result = mysql_query($query); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 

echo "<li><span class='name'><b>$row[produkt]";
  }  
?>
</ul>   
</div>
<div id="footer">You could <b><a href="Submit.html"><span style="text-decoration: "><span style="color: #ff006f; ">su</span>bm<span style="color: #fff70a; ">it</span>
</a>
 </b>more Products to help us.
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

after wrong deleting my last question here is it again.
At the moment if i open the page it give me all informations that are in the database, at last i want just to see the products that i search for ... any one could help please :( getting really frustrated

Comment: Assuming what's shown above is accurate, you may wish to change your database password after posting this question... :S

Comment: just a warning: your code can very easily be injected with nasty stuff. Imagine for example if I wrote "(DELETE FROM produkt)" in the search filed, it would delete everything in that table. Be sure to check the search strings before executing the queries.

Comment: @Avada: You would search for produkts whose id contain the string (DELETE FROM produkt)? If you were attempting to illustrate some kind of attack, you failed to do so. You can't do anything malicious with this query except cause it to not execute or cause it to return all rows of the produkts table (not a very scary thing for a search page). You can't execute multiple queries with `mysql_query` so you can't prematurely end this query and inject a second one to run either.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: I was indeed trying to illustrate malicious injection. Not being an expert on the subject I thought that `mysql_query` accepted nested queries, which in case it did would in this case be dangerous. Thanks your straighten me out!

Answer (score 2):

Your `<input>` tag has no `name` attribute, so it populates no keys in `$_GET`.

Add `name="search"` to the input tag, then `$_GET['search']` will have what you searched for.

You are confusing the meaning/purpose of `id` and `name`. `id` just provides a target for javascript/CSS, it is not something that becomes part of the form data.

Comment: Like this <input id="submit" type="hidden" name="search" /></fieldset> and <?php $['search'] ?> could see live at http://fskonferenz.de/fabian/Search.php

Comment: No. The input where you type the search query should be the one named search. `$['search']` is not even a valid PHP syntax.

Comment: about what line are you talking its my first php project :(

Comment: This is HTML, not PHP.  It's this line. `<input id="search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />`

Comment: so it should be <input id="$['search']" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting these ideas, or why you're not reading what I write.. my answer says "add `name="search"` to the input tag." Here's what that looks like: `<input name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for a Product" type="text" />`. I also already said that `$['search']` is not valid PHP code for anything, so why would you think to add that again somewhere else? I'm very confused...

Comment: same here ^^i did this before ^^ so maybe you could see still getting wrong "url" http://fskonferenz.de/fabian/Search.php updated the code here also so you could see my uptodate code

Comment: Now you have the right HTML. You can see that the search query is now part of the URL after you submit the form. You used to have the right code (`$search = $_GET['search']`) to use it. You should not have changed that. Put it back.

Comment: so i replaced 
$_GET['search']; -  $search = $_GET['search']; still no changes

Comment: You have two inputs named search now. Fix that. Your code is fine otherwise. If it still doesn't work then do some debugging of your own. I can't handhold you through every line of work.

Comment: shared the hole code ^^ edit the code again to up to date code